# Angular.js <div ng-include> not filling vertical veiwport

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Using Angular.Js, I am trying to make a single page app where the with the scrolling effect. I want each ng-inlcude section... the `<div class="viewport" ng-include="'views/file'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>` to fill the viewport. However, it' not.

I set the html and body to 100% in CSS, and then each ng-include the same. However, I still can not make each div fill the viewport. I am not sure if the actual parent HTML and body are being sized percentage wise, since the logic is for the children to fill percentage wise to the parent.

```
  <body ng-app="myappApp">
    <div id="sidebar-back-drop"></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div id="sidebar-bar-static" class="col-xs-2">
        <a href="#fakelink" id="button" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-inverse">Home</a>
        <a href="#fakelink" id="button" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-inverse">Weather</a>
        <a href="#fakelink" id="button" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-inverse">Stocks</a>
        <a href="#fakelink" id="button" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-inverse">News</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="viewport" ng-include="'views/home.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    <div class="viewport" ng-include="'views/first.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    <div class="viewport" ng-include="'views/first.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    <div class="viewport" ng-include="'views/first.html'" ng-controller="MainCtrl"></div>
    </div>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
```

css:

```
html {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #f39c12;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#title {
}



#sidebar-bar-static {
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    color: #1abc9c #34495e;
}

#sidebar-back-drop {
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 181px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#button {
    width: 121px;
    height: 41px;

.viewport {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing tag:

```
#button {
  width: 121px;
  height: 41px;
} // <----- this one is not in yours.
```